# Reordering ggplot stacked barchat

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

Trying to reorder columns in my based on total blank and 'N/A' values.

```
ggplot(quality_melted, aes(x = Column, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Data Quality Inspection: Blanks and 'N/A' Responses", x = "Columns", y = "Count")
```

Tried using something like `x = reorder(Column, NA_blank_Count)` but that wasn't working for me. Sorry I cannot provide the visualization output; I'm working with sensitive data.

Comment: If you are using sensitive data, please provide a mock data frame that shows the essence of your data.  For example, we don't know the types of your columns, we don't know which column(s) you want to count the blanks in, and we don't even know if you have a column called `NA_blank_count`. I appreciate you can't share your data, but if you want help you have to provide enough information to allow folks here to help you.

Comment: At the moment your question is equivalent to "here's some syntactically correct code. Please guess why my data causes it to output a picture that you cannot see but I can"

Answer (score 1):

**`reorder()` works on factor only**

You need to convert your Column as factor and you can actually define the order during the operation, like:

```
#sample column with NA. change Column values according to your actual data
Column<- c(NA, 'Blank', 'Blank')
Column%>%factor(levels=c('Blank', NA), exclude = NULL)
#level order defined
[1] <NA>  Blank Blank
Levels: Blank <NA>
```

Now, if you plot, you should got the order starting with "Blank".